# Extend check zone of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, checkbox

I'm programming a menu with two checkboxes inside (mat-menu from Angular with native Javascript checkboxes) and if I'm not clicking exactly in the box that doesn't work, the menu is closing and the box not checked ...

By the way with the mat-menu I haven't found how to block the automatic closure of the menu when I click on it.

Do you have a solution ?

[Capture of my menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq8qg.png)

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->

<div class="header">
  <mat-toolbar color="warn">OpenLayers</mat-toolbar>

  <div class="menu">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Marqueurs</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <p>Piscines : <input type="checkbox" id="piscine" name="piscine" (change)="handleSelected1($event)"/></p>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <p>Parkings : <input type="checkbox" id="parking" name="parking" (change)="handleSelected2($event)"/></p>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the relevant markup in the question.

Comment: So you are not using a label?

Comment: I can't enclose a capture of my menu but I have my menu with my two checkboxes with their label beside and I want that we can check the box by clicking on the label too, not 
necessarily exactly on the box

Comment: Excuse me for the mistake ! Now it is working, thank you very much !!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way of extending the checkbox zone using CSS `:after` pseudo-element:

```css
p, label, button, .chk-extended{
  position: relative;
}

/* The above element position will be taken as reference
   for the pseudo-element absolute positioning below:
*/

.chk-extended:after,
.chk-over-elm:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: 1px dotted gray; /* For visibility */
  /* The below can be adjusted */
  top: -0.5em;
  bottom: -0.5em;
  left: -0.5em;
  right: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
Regular:<input type="checkbox" />
<br><br>
Extended:<input class='chk-extended' type="checkbox" />
<br><br>
<label>Extended on label:<input class='chk-over-elm' type="checkbox" /></label>
<br><br>
<button>Extended on button:<input class='chk-over-elm' type="checkbox" /></button>
<br>
<p>Extended on p:<input class='chk-over-elm' type="checkbox" /></p>
```

Note that I used `p`, `label`, `button` as examples in my snippet, but it can work with anything else.
Also, you may need to use `!important` on the CSS rules to override rules that are already set.

Hope it helps.